# MySQL not commiting changes even with auto commit set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below syntax where I sorted the the date order, my default is autocommit enabled, however when I reopen the table it is not sorted again, is there some other syntax I should write to the below to make it permanent?

Thanks

```
SELECT *
FROM stock_price.spy1996
ORDER BY Date ASC;
```

Comment: Are you trying to commit `SELECT` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding several very important concepts in SQL.

First, changes to the database occur (generally) through `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE`.  These are the changes that are committed.

Second, `SELECT` does not change the database.

Third, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you want the results from a query to be in a particular order, then you have to use an `ORDER BY` clause.

If you like, you can implement a view that does this automatically:

```
CREATE VIEW v_spy_1996 as
    SELECT *
    FROM stock_price.spy1996
    ORDER BY Date ASC;
```

Then when you query from the view, you will not have to repeat the `ORDER BY`.